# access $_GET variables in external ajax search.php

Tags: php

I just set up an ajax live-search functionality for my page and I am facing issues with preserving `GET`-variables.

On my `index.php`, I have a lot of checkboxes and buttons that create `GET`-variables, such as `$_GET['category']`.

This is a part of my external `search.php` script that is called via ajax when the user searches (on index.php):

```
[...]

$query = 'SELECT row FROM table WHERE';

if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
$query = $query . ' something LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" AND';
}

if(!empty($_GET['category'])){
$query = $query . ' category LIKE "%'.$_GET['category'].'%" AND';
} 

[...]
```

Now, as you can probably imagine, this `$_GET['category']` variable does not work. How can I access it?

(it is created in index.php, I would like to access it in search.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options, these were the first that came to mind;
You could either, read out the GET variables in javascript from the URL and pass them to `search.php` as parameters (here you will have the option to use GET or POST, functionally this doesn't really matter).
Or, you can save them in a `$_SESSION` and read these values in `search.php`. This does require the `search.php` and the `index.php` to be executed on the same domain, otherwise you'd have to build some trickery with cookies.

Comment: thanks for your answer! So if I want to use `SESSION` , would I simply store it like this: `$_SESSION['category'] = $_GET['category']` ?

Comment: Yes! And then in your `search.php` you can use `$_SESSION['category']` to read the value.
However, do *not* *ever* pass user generated input directly into a query, this is a very bad idea because this leaves your database vulnerable for SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using $_REQUEST['category'] instead of $_GET['category']. you may be  access your variable.

Answer (score 0):

[...]

if(isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])){

[...]

This check is sufficient.